# Search/Browse: Unified or separate?

Tags: search, web

Most websites allow you to both search and browse the site. However, on some sites, such as eBay and Amazon.com, browsing eventually leads you to a search results screen with an empty search box. Is this desireable? Should 'search' and 'browse' be the same thing? Personally, I find it much easier on product-based sites, for example, to browse by slowly filtering down all the results (e.g. "all products" > "bikes" > "mountain bikes" > "mens' mountain bikes" etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Users, how ever mysterious they may be, use the both techniques to find what thay need. It's an ongoing iteration of serach > browse > search > browse technique. So I would say they are very much unified in the concept of finding information which is the whole purpose of search/browse in the first place.

[image]

Peter Morville described this pattern in his infamous book [IA for the WWW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596527349) and the more recent book [Search Patterns](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596802277). As an IA myself I recomend both these books, since they are a good reference to the world of IA and the users consuming IA every day.